# Getting SqlSession when extending SqlSessionDaoSupport

Tags: java, session, mybatis

I would like to obtain SqlSession on my mapper class using "extends SqlSessionDaoSupport" in my SpringBoot app.

```html
public class SearchRepository extends SqlSessionDaoSupport{

    private final SearchTmpMapper mapper;

    public SqlSession searchTmp() {

        SearchFilter filter = intializeFilter();
        mapper.searchTmp(filter);
        
        return this.getSqlSession();
}

public interface SearchTmpMapper {

    void searchTmp(
            @Param("filter") SearchFilter filter);
}

<select id="searchTmp">
        /* some SQL select */
</select>
```

But I am facing "IllegalArgumentException: Property 'sqlSessionFactory' or 'sqlSessionTemplate' are required" error. I have added this to my POM file.

```html
<dependency>
<groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
<version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

But I cannot start the application because od this error. Do you have some advice?

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to achieve, but the posted code does not look right. Please read the [documentation](https://mybatis.org/spring/sqlsession.html#SqlSessionDaoSupport).

Answer (score 1):

> `SqlSessionDaoSupport` requires either an `sqlSessionFactory` or an `sqlSessionTemplate` property to be set. If both properties are set, the `sqlSessionFactory` is ignored.

Please try `super.setSqlSessionTemplate(sqlSessionTemplate);` or `super.setSqlSessionFactory(sqlSessionFactory);` when initializing the `SearchRepository`.